# Find out current iterm2 color scheme?

Tags: iterm2

I know that I can set my color scheme for iterm2 in Preferences -> Profiles -> Colors.  I found a scheme that I like, but I can't remember which one it is, and the dropdown from which I selected it just says "Load Presets...".

Is there any way to find out what my current color scheme is?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, there is a checkmark next to the current theme.
But if you change anything, the checkmark goes away and your essentially creating a custom theme.

I tend to export the color and put into a personal settings directory.  I backup this directory and put up on github. That may work for you.

If you import this exported theme file, then there will be a theme with the name of your file, and it will have a checkmark next to it. At least it does for me.